# Links do not have a discernible name

Tags: hyperlink, pagespeed

I have seen multiple posts about this, apoligies for the repitition, but there isn't a secondary solution I found in the thread.

I added a custome atribute to my website for the above error "Links do not have a discernible name" from page speed insight.

aria-label="give us a call" (which I found on another thread, it mentioned it can be longer and it didn't mention you can't add spaces)

but I still get the same page speed score, I am using elementor (who basically sent me here as they cannot fix it)

and because of my lack of knowledge, I am stuck on how to fix it

my URL: fangioautohermanus.co.za

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zueeg.png)

added: aria-label="give us a call" under custom attributes in the icon box

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.